# Firebase setDoc hangs without any error in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

`setDoc` will hang half the time I call it. If I sleep for a second before calling it, it always succeeds with the doc write. I don't know why there'd be a race condition.

The call to `await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...)` always works, but the call to `setDoc` fails no matter how I try writing it.

I'm upgrading from the `compat` libraries which worked perfectly on doc writes.

Here are my Cloud Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      // allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 12, 11);
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my Signup component that calls my Firebase auth service:

```
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

...

    async signupUser() {
        try {
            let emailLower = this.signupForm.value.email.toLowerCase();
            const user: User = {
                id: emailLower,
                email: this.signupForm.value.email,
                emailLower: emailLower,
                accountType: 'endUser',
                displayName: this.signupForm.value.displayName,
                displayNameLower: this.signupForm.value.displayName.toLowerCase(),
                newsletter: this.signupForm.value.newsletter,
            };
            const password = this.signupForm.value.password;

            // console.log('sleeping...');
            // await this.sleep(1000);
            // console.log('woke up');

            const result = await this.authService.signup(user, password);
            if (result == null) {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            } else if (result.isValid === false) {
                this.errorMessage = this.getFriendlyErrorMessage(result.code);
            }
            } catch (error) {
               console.error('Error during signup:', error);
            }
        }
```

Here's the auth.service.ts file with the `setDoc` call...

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth, sendEmailVerification, sendPasswordResetEmail, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
import { addDoc, Firestore, collection, doc, setDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
...

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

constructor(private router: Router, private firestore: Firestore, private http: HttpClient, private fns: Functions) {...}


async signup(user: User, password: string): Promise<{ isValid: boolean; code?: string; message?: string } | null> {
        const auth = getAuth();

        try {
            const result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, password);       
            const userDoc = doc(this.firestore, 'users', user.emailLower);                          

            try {
                await setDoc(userDoc, user);
                console.log('auth setDoc: success');
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('auth setDoc: error:', error);
                return null;
            }

            if (result && result.user) {
                await sendEmailVerification(result.user);

            } else {
                console.log("Auth Service: User creation succeeded but unable to send verification email. No user in result.");
            }

            return null;                                                    // success
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('auth service: signup error:', error);
            return { isValid: false, code: error.code, message: error.message };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any solution? I am having this hanging with setDoc, mainly when firebase client is in heavily used local network. After many minutes it throws an error: @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.1): GrpcConnection RPC 'Write' stream ... error. Code: 14 Message: 14 UNAVAILABLE: read ETIMEDOUT. After this error, it restart to resolve again for some time, until it hangs one more time.

Comment: I couldn't find any reason for the race, so I went back to the `compat` libraries to be safe

Comment: I had some issues with storage also, but they were resolved by disabling ipv6 in the system or connection (Linux). Maybe, there is something related to it.